# jQuery :not selector and hash symbol syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm getting a lovely Syntax error. It's when I try to select all anchor tags without an href containing a placeholder URL, i.e. `href="#"`.

I've tried the following:

```
$("a:not(href='#')");

//swapped single with double quotes
$('a:not(href="#")');

// no quotes at all
$("a:not(href=#)");

// wildcard selector
$("a:not(href*=#)");
```

And all of them result in the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: href=#(…)

Any ideas?

---

Snippet below:

```js
var $item = $("a:not(href='#')");
console.log($item);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://google.com">Selected</a>
<a href="#">Not selected</a>
```

Comment: @Vohuman I did. I just overlooked it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The test for the `href` needs to be in square brackets:

```
$("a:not([href='#'])")
```

The brackets are there because that's how you do an attribute value test in CSS selectors. If you were just looking for elements with that `href`, for example, it'd look like

```
$("[href='#']")
```

Comment: Thank you! Too think I missed such a simple thing.